# How do I delete ALL Chrome Autofill entries besides saved addresses?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

I seem to have found the option to delete ONLY the addresses or ALL the Autofill data, but since Chrome can tell the addresses apart, isn't there a way to delete ALL 2000+ of the NON addresses? These don't even appear in search boxes, they only seem to appear when I need them. They are ALL I want to keep of the BS autofill data crap.